# Safari doesn’t detect my Extension Certificate

Tags: safari, certificate

all! I have registered for the Safari Development Program and have a valid Apple ID. I've followed all the steps given by Apple. The problem is that Windows XP (Service Pack 2) does not recognize the command 'certreq', whereas the instructions said it would work on any Windows machine. However, the command 'certreq' was working on Windows Vista on the machine of my co-worker's, I downloaded the certificate (the .cer file) and installed it and Safari detected it. However, I don't have Windows Vista. I installed Windows 7 now on my machine, the command 'certreq' works and I have the Safari Extension Certificate (the .cer file) but when I open Safari's Extension Builder, my certificate does not appear there.

I entered mmc in Start --> Run and checked if the certificate was installed there. It was in the 'Other People' but not in 'Personal'. Even on Internet Explorer 7+, when I go to Tools --> Internet Options --> Content (Tab) --> Certificates, the certificate is not there in the Personal tab, (WHEREAS IT GOT INSTALLED IN THE PERSONAL FOLDER AUTOMATICALLY IN WINDOWS VISTA). I tried importing the certificate (the .cer file) into the Peronal folder, the import is successful but still neither does it appear in the personal folder nor does Safari recognize/detect it when I go to the Extension Builder.

ANY HELP?! I need to make an extension for my office project and the deadline is approaching. I really need to get it done.

Thanks a million in anticipation.

Comment: Cross-posted on Stack Overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061769/safari-doesnt-detect-my-extension-certificate

Answer (score 2):

The way to prove that a public key certificate is your own is to have the **private** key that goes along with it. A .cer file is just the public key certificate, so it won't show up as your personal certificate unless you can find the *private* key that matches it and get that installed too.

The `certreq` command probably created the private-public key pair, stored the *private* key somewhere in the Windows Certificate Store, and packaged up just the *public* key as part of a Certificate Signing Request (CSR) to send to Apple.  Apple probably signed your CSR to generate your public key certificate (.cer), but you were expected to know where your private key was and to make sure you got your private key into the proper user's local certificate store.

Answer (score 1):

when you enter something like "certmgr.msc" in the run command in window, you will get to see something like this:

So using the certificate consists of the following steps:

1. first save the file and run the command in cmdd.exe as directed in the developer certificate generator in extension certificate developer.
2. when you are done, check the certmgr [shown above in the image] and see a certificate named safari developer installed somewhere near Certificate Enrollment Requests. cut the certificate and paste one copy inside trusted root certification Authorities and another inside Personal.
3. then generate the csr file and install the file inside Personal folder and trusted root certification Authorities folder.
4. extension builder will recognize the certificate.

Best of luck.